# PXE Download Files from TFTP Server

Tags: fedora, pxe, tftp

I just started working on PXE network booting and successfully configured servers(DHCP and TFTP) and a client. Everything is working well.

DHCP and TFTP servers are configured on Fedora 13 and OS that boots on network is also a stripped down version of Fedora 13.

Following is a part of menu file

> label linux0
>
> menu label Fedora 13 (Minimal)
>
> kernel fc/vmlinuz0
>
> APPEND rootflags=loop
>   initrd=fc/initrd0.img
>   root=live:/myfc13.iso
>   rootfstype=iso9660 rw
>
> liveimg quiet selinux=0 rhgb
>   rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD noiswmd blacklist
>   nouveau

Client successfully displays the menu and boot the OS.

Both the following files were downloaded from tftp server to client

> vmlinuz0
>
> initrd0.img

What i now wanted is to download some other files(some text files) from the tftp server to client, so is this possible and how?

Any suggestion?

> NOTE: I can add the files in the
>   kernel image but this is the last
>   solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built-in for that. Modify either the initrd or the install to pull down the files after the system has started.

Comment: what do mean by install?

Comment: The operating system that PXE boots up.